# a groovy switch case statement with several variables

Tags: groovy, switch-statement

Is it possible to have a switch-case statement with more than a variable in groovy?  I tried with tuples but the case part doesn't accept more than one argument.

I am trying to avoid several nested if statements so instead of

```
if (a==1) {
  if (b==2) {
    if (c==3) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
else {
  if (a==4) {
    if (b==5) {
      if (c==6) {
        //do something else 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I do:

```
switch(a,b,c) { 
  case : (1,2,3) // if a==1, b==2 and c==3
    // do something 
    ... 
  case : (4,5,6)
    // do something else  
    ... 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Groovy is just dirty java, you don't need any class definition. everything you write in a java method you can write it directly in groovy.

```
switch (num) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
   System.out.println("1 through 3");
   break;
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
    System.out.println("6 through 8");
 break;
}
```

To answer your question, inside the switch we need an expression, not function parameters.

Comment: thanks. That would work for one criteria and several values, but I need to test on a set of criteria. I edited my question for (hopefully) more clarity

Comment: if it has multiple criteria, then use if() like.. if (a==1 && b==2 &&  c==3){do this ;} else if( a==4 && b==5 && c==6){then do that;} else if() ........

Comment: You mean "groovy is just way nicer java", right? :-)

Comment: Yeah, we don't need any class or method definition. Just write it as a script and tell it what to do.. and it will do. :) But if one needs to create methods and classes , it can be done. I used it to create scripts

Comment: `Groovy is just dirty java`

A bit irrelevant but this made my day!! Thanks @Groot

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit, I believe that this should work:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 3) {
  // do something
} else if (a == 4 && b == 5 && c == 6) {
  // do something else
}
```

If you want a switch statement instead, that's possible:

```
def val = [a, b, c]
switch (val) {
    case {it == [1, 2, 3]}:
        // something
        break;
    case {it == [4, 5, 6]}:
        // something else
        break;
```

Comment: Obviously any switch can be defined in an if-else chain, but when you have >2 cases switch just looks better

Comment: Looking at this again now (I had forgotten about it) I completely agree with you...switch is much more readable.

Comment: @Daniel can you elaborate on what this groovy/java construct is that putting a condition in curly braces makes it work for a case condition? Just a term I can search for would be enough. Thanks.

Comment: I'd search for "groovy closure".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution{
 static void main (String...args){
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in))
def val=br.readLine()        
     switch(val){
       case('E0'):
         println "Basic"
         break;
         default:
         break;
         case('E1'):
         println "Inter"
         break;
         case('E2'):
         println "Advance"
         break;
       default:
       println "not defined"
       
              }
          
  }
}
```

Comment: unable to achieve the all ouput

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).